# grep - q "$1[^_-]"

Tags: regex, grep

Can anyone explain what this gibberish means :

`"[^_-]"`

from

`grep - q "$1[^_-]"`

I've done a `man grep`and found nothing.

Comment: To help frame a helpful answer, how much do you already know about regular expressions? Are you looking for an introduction to regular expressions generally? Or do you have some familiarity with regexps, but don't know about characters classes? Or do you know about character classes but are unable to read this character class specifically?

Answer (score 1):

You can find the definition of those characters using `info grep` and navigating to "3 Regular Expressions" and then "3.2 Character Classes and Bracket Expressions" (available online [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html#Character-Classes-and-Bracket-Expressions)):

> A **bracket expression** is a list of characters enclosed by ‘[’ and ‘]’. It matches any single character in that list. If the first character of the list is the caret ‘^’, then it matches any character not in the list.
>
> - ‘-’ represents the range if it’s not first or last in a list or the ending point of a range.
> - ‘^’ represents the characters not in the list. If you want to make the ‘^’ character a list item, place it anywhere but first.

So `"$1[^_-]"` should match whatever is in your variable `$1` followed by *one* character that is not `_` or `-`.

Comment: Well, that was obvious (not!). Thanks very much for explaining. Someone needs to come up with regex that's actually easy to understand. It seems like every regex you come across has a different set of rules. Perl uses `//`. grep uses `[]`. etc

Comment: Please accept my answer if it was useful so that this question can be considered closed.